# How to search a nested object for a specific value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object with nested objects inside that I am trying to search for specific values. Here's the object:

```
var obj = {
    "usa": {
        "rate": 20,
        "pop": 250000
    },
    "can": {
        "rate": 10,
        "pop": 200999
    },
    "mex": {
        "rate": 45,
        "pop": 150230
    }
};
```

Now, how would I search for the rate of each country, depending on which country the user hover's over? (The id of each country is saved as the country's e.shapeid with the library I'm using, such as usa, can, mex, etc.). The logic I'm looking for is:

```
obj{ e.shapeid{ rate }}
```

so that the box that comes up when the user hovers can select the correct rate to be shown for each country. Is there a good way to search for those rates?

Comment: You are thinking right, just change your `{` and `}` for `[` and `]`, aka `obj[e.shapeid]['rate']`

Comment: Or can use dot notation after `[variable]` ... `obj[e.shapeid].rate`